# Class decorator to auto-update properties dictionary on disk?

Tags: python, class, decorator

I am working on a project where I have a number of custom classes to interface with a varied collection of data on a user's system. These classes only have `properties` as user-facing attributes. Some of these properties are decently resource intensive, so I want to only run the generation code once, and store the returned value on disk (cache it, that is) for faster retrieval on subsequent runs. As it stands, this is how I am accomplishing this:

```
def stored_property(func):
    """This ``decorator`` adds on-disk functionality to the `property`
    decorator. This decorator is also a Method Decorator.

    Each key property of a class is stored in a settings JSON file with
    a dictionary of property names and values (e.g. :class:`MyClass`
    stores its properties in `my_class.json`). 
    """
    @property
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(self):
        print('running decorator...')
        try:
            var = self.properties[func.__name__]
            if var:
                # property already written to disk
                return var
            else:
                # property written to disk as `null`
                return func(self)
        except AttributeError:
            # `self.properties` does not yet exist
            return func(self)
        except KeyError:
            # `self.properties` exists, but property is not a key
            return func(self)
    return func_wrapper

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, wf):
        self.wf = wf
        self.properties = self._properties()

    def _properties(self):
        # get name of class in underscore format
        class_name = convert(self.__class__.__name__)
        # this is a library used (in Alfred workflows) for interacted with data stored on disk
        properties = self.wf.stored_data(class_name)
        # if no file on disk, or one of the properties has a null value
        if properties is None or None in properties.values():
            # get names of all properties of this class
            propnames = [k for (k, v) in self.__class__.__dict__.items()
                         if isinstance(v, property)]
            properties = dict()
            for prop in propnames:
                # generate dictionary of property names and values
                properties[prop] = getattr(self, prop)
            # use the external library to save that dictionary to disk in JSON format
            self.wf.store_data(class_name, properties,
                               serializer='json')
        # return either the data read from file, or data generated in situ
        return properties

    #this decorator ensures that this generating code is only run if necessary
    @stored_property
    def only_property(self):
        # some code to get data
        return 'this is my property'
```

This code works precisely as I need it, but it still forces me to manually add the `_properties(self)` method to each class wherein I need this functionality (currently, I have 3). What I want is a way to "insert" this functionality into any class I please. I think that a Class Decorator could get this job done, but try as I might, I can't quite figure out how to wrangle it.

For the sake of clarity (and in case a decorator is not the best way to get what I want), I will try to explain the overall functionality I am after. I want to write a class that contains some properties. The values of these properties are generated via various degrees of complex code (in one instance, I'm searching for a certain app's pref file, then searching for 3 different preferences (any of which may or may not exist) and determining the best single result from those preferences). I want the body of the properties' code only to contain the algorithm for finding the data. But, I don't want to run that algorithmic code each time I access that property. Once I generate the value once, I want to write it to disk and then simply read that on all subsequent calls. However, I don't want each value written to its own file; I want a dictionary of all the values of all the properties of a single class to be written to one file (so, in the example above, `my_class.json` would contain a JSON dictionary with one key, value pair). When accessing the property directly, it should first check to see if it already exists in the dictionary on disk. If it does, simply read and return that value. If it exists, but has a null value, then try to run the generation code (i.e. the code actually written in the property method) and see if you can find it now (if not, the method will return `None` and that will once again be written to file). If the dictionary exists and that property is not a key (my current code doesn't really make this possible, but better safe than sorry), run the generation code and add the key, value pair. If the dictionary doesn't exist (i.e. on the first instantiation of the class), run all generation code for all properties and create the JSON file. Ideally, the code would be able to update one property in the JSON file without rerunning all of the generation code (i.e. running `_properties()` again).

I know this is a bit peculiar, but I need the speed, human-readable content, and elegant code all together. I would really not to have to compromise on my goal. Hopefully, the description of what I want it clear enough. If not, let me know in a comment what doesn't make sense and I will try to clarify. But I do think that a Class Decorator could probably get me there (essentially by inserting the `_properties()` method into any class, running it on instantiation, and mapping its value to the `properties` attribute of the class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem that your `_properties` method is specific to the properties that a given class has. I'd put that in a base class and have each of your classes with `@stored_property` methods subclass that. Then you don't need to duplicate the `_properties` method.

```
class PropertyBase(object):
    def __init__(self, wf):
        self.wf = wf
        self.properties = self._properties()

    def _properties(self):
        # As before...

class MyClass(PropertyBase):
    @stored_property
    def expensive_to_calculate(self):
        # Calculate it here
```

If for some reason you can't subclass `PropertyBase` directly (maybe you already need to have a different base class), you can probably use a mixin. Failing that, make `_properties` accept an instance/class and a workflow object and call it explicitly in `__init__` for each class.

Comment: Great point. I had only just now fully abstracted the `_properties()` method, and hadn't realized that once I abstracted it, I could use a base class. This also would seem to be cleaner and more communicative than using a Class Decorator.